# find position of nearest nonzero element in an array (functionally)

Tags: functional-style

Given an array `sel` and an index position `i0`, how can I find the position of the nearest (left or right) nonzero element?
I'm able to do it with a loop and a couple of awful If's, but I was looking for a functional way...

```
    lr=Length[sel];
    For[i = 0, i <= lr, i++,
       If[1 <= i0 + i <= lr && sel[[i0 + i]] == 1, Print[i0+i]; Break[],
        If[1 <= i0 - i <= lr && sel[[i0 - i]] == 1, Print[i0-i];Break[]]]]
```

Comment: How large are the lists you're dealing with and how important is speed? The methods posted so far can be handily beaten, but if speed is not a primary concern, no need for added complexity.

Comment: they're not big - my concern was to learn doing things functionally. Unfortunately, I find the 3 methods proposed so far a bit hard to understand: I'm working on it. Seems to me this is one of those unfortunate cases were the iterative paradigm is clearer to understand and maybe more elegant...

Comment: Don't get discouraged - functional and MMA can take some time to wrap one's head around. I'd be happy to post an "answer" that goes step-by-step on using `Nearest` if you'd like. Also, take a look at `LengthWhile`...  it does what your loop does in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
nearestNonNull[lst_, i_] := 
  First@MinimalBy[
    Select[MapIndexed[Flatten@{#1 != 0, #2} &, lst],
    TrueQ@First@# &][[All, 2]], Abs[i - #] &]

sel = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, 10^4];
nearestNonNull[sel, 1234];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nrstNZP[l_] := With[{nF = Nearest[Flatten@SparseArray[l]["NonzeroPositions"]]}, 
      With[{nrst = nF[#, 2]}, DeleteCases[nrst, #][[1]]] & /@ #] &
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
sel = RandomInteger[{0, 2}, 20]
(* {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 1} *)
Flatten[SparseArray[sel]["NonzeroPositions"]]
(* {1, 3, 4, 8, 13, 15, 16, 19, 20} *)

nrstNZP[sel] @ Range[20]
(* {3, 1, 4, 3, 4, 4, 8, 4, 8, 8, 13, 13, 15, 13, 16, 15, 16, 19, 20, 19} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generalization of the above to work with arrays (lists) of arbitrary depth. Also avoids checking the element at your specified position (something which may or may not be desired).

```
nearestNZP = 
  Function[{array, i}, 
   MinimalBy[
    Flatten[MapIndexed[
      If[#1 != 0 && #2 != i, #2, Unevaluated[Sequence[]]] &, 
      array, {Length@i}], Length@i - 1], Norm[# - i] &]];
```

Define array (5x5 matrix in my example):

```
ar = RandomInteger[{-3, 3}, {5, 5}]
```

> `{{-3, 3, -2, -2, 2}, {-1, -2, 0, -3, -3}, {-1, -1, -2, 1, 1},
>   {2, 3, -1, 0, 1}, {-3, 0, -3, 1, -2}}`

```
nearestNZP[ar, {2, 2}]
```

> `{{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}}`

The depth at which the function works is determined by the length of the list of numbers specifying the index position. For a 1D array the index should be specified as `nearestNZP[array, {1234}]` rather than `nearestNZP[array, 1234]`.